# How to generate a new email at every registration using Cypress

Tags: cypress

This is my HTML for email field

```
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="">
```

How can I write cypress command so that a new email id is generated everytime with a + sign. Eg- Parent email address is test@gmail.com. Subsequent email address should be test+a1@gmail.com , test+a2@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Javascript class with static method to keep track of the number used.

Because the static property is inside the class definition, it is not cleared by Cypress between tests.

You can also move it to `/support/index.js` and create a custom command to use across multiple spec files.

```js
class EmailGenerator {

  static id = 1;
  static generate(baseEmail) {
    const uniqueId = `+a${this.id++}`;  
    return baseEmail.replace('@', `${uniqueId}@`); 
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('generateEmail', (baseEmail) => {
  return EmailGenerator.generate(baseEmail)
})

it('generates a unique email', () => {
  console.log(EmailGenerator.generate('test@gmail.com'))    // test+a1@gmail.com
})

it('generates a second unique email', () => {
  console.log(EmailGenerator.generate('test@gmail.com'))    // test+a2@gmail.com
})

it('generates a third unique email via a custom command (across all specs)', () => {
  cy.generateEmail('test@gmail.com')
    .then(email => console.log(email));                     // test+a3@gmail.com
})

it('puts unique emails into the input', () => {

  cy.get('input[name="email"]')
    .type(EmailGenerator.generate('test@gmail.com'))        // test+a4@gmail.com

  cy.get('input[name="email"]')
    .type(EmailGenerator.generate('test@gmail.com'))        // test+a5@gmail.com

})
```

Comment: That is a very good solution for cases you need to track the generated number of emails. Thank you for showing a different way.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov I think your way (the "functional"  rather than "class" way) is just as valid. I wanted to experiment with ways of protecting data from cleardown. Not sure if there's anything better in this approach.

Comment: Probably if you write them down in a fixture file with command `cy.writeFile()`

Answer (score 0):

[Faker](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) is a nice library specialized in generating random data. For your case, after you install it you can use something like this:

```
let email =  `test+` + faker.random.uuid() + '@domain.com'
```

Another variant - using JS and the fact that you can store variables only in arrays and Objects inside the cypress code:

```
let numberOfEmails = {counter: 0}
function generateEmail(numberOfEmails){
   numberOfEmail.counter++
   return `test+a${numberOfEmail.counter}@gmail.com`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fakerjs is good but when you generate new emails you don't receive them because you don't own the domain.

I saw a nice tool that does both randomizes the email address and open the email and test emails.

It's basically a recorder, you don't have to write Cypress scripts at all.

https://cypress.preflight.com/